# Inject spring custom scope bean in JSF 2 application

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I am making using of custom spring managed view scope bean within a JSF2 - Spring application. I want to inject the bean into a request scope bean. However it looks like I am getting a new instance of the custom view scope bean every time the request scope bean is called.

My view scope bean is as below

```
@Component("registration")
@Scope("view")
public class RegistrationBean implements Serializable
```

My request scope bean is as follows

```
@Component("registrationController")
@Scope("request")
public class RegistrationController implements Serializable
{
@Autowired(required=false) 
@Qualifier("registration")  
private RegistrationBean registration;  
  .....

}
```

If I make use of the view scope bean directly within my facelets, all my values are preserved. However if I access the same through my request scope bean the values don't get preserved.

Based on my research I can see examples where a JSF managed view scope bean injected into JSF managed request scope bean, however I could not find any instance of the above mentioned problem.

Any information in understanding this issue is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wanted to add that if I convert my custom view scope bean to standard session scope bean, then everything works fine . I can access it properly from my request scope bean.

Comment: Do you directly access the View scoped bean in your facelets? If you don't, in your request scoped Bean a new instance might be created (I am not sure how Spring does on top of JSF). But as anything created in the request, it is destroyed with the request end. Next request just re-create a new instance of the 'registration'.

Comment: I do access the view scoped bean directly in my facelets. I want to access the view bean in the controller when I am performing actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at my view scopes implementation for Spring.

See my github [javaplugs/spring-jsf](https://github.com/javaplugs/spring-jsf) repository.